# Why does this command work on my terminal but not in my code?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, netstat

This doesn't work and says that there's no such file or directory

```
current_conecctions = subprocess.Popen("netstat -p udp",shell = False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

While `netstat -p udp` works perfectly in the terminal.

Comment: You probably want to avoid `Popen` anyway; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use a list of parameters instead of a single string:

```
command = ["netstat", "-p", "udp"]
current_conecctions = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```